# Java How to create Array length based on user input & How to Assign a Number value to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, string-length

So what this program is supposed to do is, the user enters a String, the program will check each character from charAt(0) to charAt(length of string - 1)
and it will check to see if it is a valid letter( A-Z or a-z). Anything non-letter is considered a word separator.

The counter will increment every time the next character is a letter. The counter will reset to 0 once the character is invalid(Number, symbol, punctuation, Spaces etc) and the chacter before the invalid character to the last valid character(in this case charAt(0) let's say) would create word 1. When the character is invalid, it will assign the counter to an array initially starting with an index of 0, and then will increment the index so it can be assigned to the next word length.

How do I create an array based on the number of words created in this program? If for example if I enter the following string, The array would be a length of 7.

> What is 8this pro98gram doin8g?
>
> Word1= What, Word2= is, Word3=this, Word4=pro, word5=gram, word6=doin, word7=g.

Also, how do I assign a number value to a specific array index, for example word[a] where a is 0,1,2,3,4,etc, every time it enters the else statement in the program.

This is what I've done so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCountInString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = 0; // Initial index is 0;
    int[] word = new int[a]; // Creating an array.

    String string;
    System.out.print("Enter a String of Data Please: ");
    string = input.nextLine();
    
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        
        if (string.charAt(i) >= 'a' && string.charAt(i) >= 'z' // Check to see if charAt(i) is a letter.
                || string.charAt(i) >= 'A' && string.charAt(i) <= 'Z') { 
            counter++; // Counter every time the next char is a letter.
        }

        else {
            word[a] = counter; // Assign the array of index(a) to counter
            a++; // Go to the next index.
            counter = 0; // Reset the counter to create a new word.

        }

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < word.length; j++) { //Prints out all the arrays.
        System.out.println(word[j]); // Print the value of each array.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have to go through the string twice--the first time you'll determine how many words there are.  You could do this by counting the number of non-letters.  Then if `n` is the number of words, you can create `new int[n]` or `new String[n]` based on what you need to do.  If you're allowed to use an `ArrayList`, that would be better since you don't need to know beforehand how big it will be.  But if you have to use an array, this would be one way.

Comment: I haven't learn about Interfaces yet, so I can't use interfaces yet. But I'm getting an error while running the program. Why is that?

Comment: @Majestic maybe you should tell us what error you are getting to help you with your code.

Comment: It's a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" at line 24 which is the line at  "word[a] = counter" in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code the error you are getting is when you are trying to increment a with a++.

```
word[a] = counter; // Assign the array of index(a) to counter
a++; // Go to the next index.
```

However you are never resizing the array. You cannot simply increment the value for the array index. This will look for an index in the array which does not yet exist.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QnA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] word = new int[0]; // Creating an array.

        String string;
        System.out.print("Enter a String of Data Please: ");
        string = input.nextLine();

        // Close the scanner --
        input.close();

        //string = "What is 8this pro98gram doin8g?";

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            //System.out.println("Test");
            // Check to see if charAt(i) is a letter.
            if (Character.isLetter(string.charAt(i))) {             
                // Counter every time the next char is a letter.
                counter++;
            } else {
                // Check if there are any valid characters
                if (counter > 0) {
                    // Resize the array and add the new char count
                    word = addToArray(word, counter);
                    // Reset the counter to create a new word.
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        /* if the last characters in the string were letters then we need to
         * add the last count to the array
        */
        if (counter > 0) {
            // Resize the array and add the new char count
            word = addToArray(word, counter);
        }
        // Prints out all the arrays.
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            // Print the value of each array.
            System.out.println(word[j]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] addToArray(int[] array, int charCount){
        // Resize the array
        array = resizeArray(array, array.length + 1);
        // Get the length and reduce 1 to get the last array index
        array[array.length - 1] = charCount;

        return array;
    }

    public static int[] resizeArray(int[] arrayToResize, int size) {
        // create a temp array
        int[] tempArray = new int[size];

        // check if the new size is different to the new size
        if (arrayToResize.length != size) {
            // copy array contents to new array
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayToResize.length; i++) {
                tempArray[i] = arrayToResize[i];
            }
        } else {
            tempArray = arrayToResize;
        }
        // return copied array resized.
        return tempArray;
    }
}
```

I have put together this built on your code. You need to look at the two functions at the end of the code; addToArray and resizeArray.

These take care of adding the new count to the array and also resizing the array to a size bigger than it was.

A much more elegant way to do this is using a list since you can simply add the next count without needing to know what the end size will be. To read more about lists check the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or a good example on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm).

Comment: Thank you David! This is very helpful!